# Capturar o backgroundColor de um Elemento em jQuery

Tags: jquery

Gente estou com um problema e não sei se é bug, porque o jQuery não está capturando o `background-color` do elemento passado pelo `css()`, estou usando um atributo `data-color` para configurar a cor do elemento, nos navegadores ele coloca a cor, segue a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu consulto no jQuery usando este comando: `$('.btn').css('backgroundColor')` ele me retorna em branco mas quando insiro o `style` funciona.

Obs.: Estou usando está função para detectar a cor e verificar se é um elemento claro ou escuro.

```
const self = $(el) // Elementos

let getBackground = (item) => {
    let background = item.css('backgroundColor'),
            alpha = parseFloat(background.split(',')[3], 10)

    if ((isNaN(alpha) || alpha > .8) && background !== 'transparent') return background

    if (item.is('body'))
        return false
    else
        return getBackground(item.parent())
}

let getLuma = (color) => {
    let rgba = color.substring(4, color.length - 1).split(','),
            r = rgba[0],
            g = rgba[1],
            b = rgba[2],
            luma = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b

    return luma
}

// Consulta
let cor = getBackground(self),
        inverse = (getLuma(cor) > 183) ? ' inverse' : '',
        $ripple = $('<div class="ink' + inverse + '"></div>')
```

Eu imaginei tentando pegar pelo atributo `data-color` para comparar mas não sei fazer no `jQuery` porque ele retorna somente o nome contido usando `data()`.

Comment: Dê um `console.log(item)` para ver se está pegando o elemento correto.

Comment: @fernandoandrade Neste caso estou usando o Framework `VueJS` e o `$(el)` é o elemento capturado e inclusive nem preciso percorrer o DOM usando o `.each()`.

Comment: Quando consulto dentro da função ele fica em branco os resultados, mas quando insiro no `style` ele funciona e me retorna em `rgb()`

Comment: No `data-color` você pode pode passar o valor como `rgb()` ou na forma `#ffffff`?

Comment: Fiz este teste de trocar mas não funcionou, estou usando `jQuery@latest # 3.1.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observando que estou dentro `VueJS`incluindo o `jQuery` dentro de um componente em "ready" lifecycle, não necessita do `document ready`, fiz alguns testes se o Vue estava passando os Elementos corretamente e depois direto no console fiz outro teste, veja a imagem:

[image: Resultado do Console.log]

Realizei um teste utilizando `console.log()` dentro da função colocando os seguintes valores:

```
let getBackground = (item) => {
    let background = item.css('backgroundColor'),
            alpha = parseFloat(background.split(',')[3], 10)

            console.log(item)
            console.log(background)

    if ((isNaN(alpha) || alpha > .8) && background !== 'transparent') return background

    if (item.is('body'))
        return false
    else
        return getBackground(item.parent())
}
```

O Resultado é que o `item` corresponde aos elementos passados pelo Vue e o `background` a cor pelo `.css()`, o que percebi parece que o Vue não está montando o elemento junto com o `data` a solução foi colocando o `document ready` mas acho errado pois fazendo o mesmo teste só que utilizando o `style` ele funciona perfeitamente.

Por isso vou abrir uma outra questão especificando o `VueJS` sobre o uso do `jQuery` de como utilizar ambos e se é necessário em cada código do `jQuery` devo utilizar o `document ready`.

Answer (score 0):

Estranho o jQuery não pegar o `background-color`, mas vamos lá:

1. Veja o que vem na variável "item" da função "getBackground";
2. Tente pegar a cor do *background* usando `item.css('background-color')`, o que era para retornar a mesma coisa utilizando assim `item.css('backgroundColor')`;
3. O seu *parseFloat* irá sempre retornar *isNan*, pois o retorno da cor "teal" pelo jQuery é "rgb(0, 150, 136)" e se você der *split(',')*, o retorno será `["rgb(0", " 150", " 136)"]`. Ou seja, se você der *parseFloat* no *index* 3, conforme está no seu código `background.split(',')[3]`, vai retornar um *isNan*. Você deve pegar o *index* 2 e retirar o parentese. `background.split(',')[2].replace(')', '')`;
4. No seu *if*, você compara a variável "background" se ela é diferente de "transparent" (`background !== 'transparent'`), porém o retorno do jQuery será `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`, fique atento a isso.

A questão principal é, ver o que está na variável "item".